# How do I check method level spring security

Tags: java, spring, url, annotations, spring-security

I have implemented spring security in controller method.

Below is my spring security.xml

-->

```
<!-- URL pattern based security -->
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" pattern="/common/admin/**" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/common/accounting/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login"/>

</security:http>
```

Below is my controller

```
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/common/admin/addAdmin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute(new Administrator());
    return "/common/admin/addAdmin";
}

@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/common/admin/addAdmin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processadd(
        @ModelAttribute("administrator") Administrator administrator) {
    this.administratorManager.addAdmin(administrator);
    return "/common/admin/success";
}
```

I allow the url /common/admin/** for both admin and user role. But i do some restriction in the admin controller. when user is go in to /common/admin/* as a user role, he can but he can also go in to method that is only for admin role only.

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have added the `@Secured` annotation.

But you need to enable it:

```
<!-- secured-annotations = (@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")) -->
<!-- jsr250-annotations = (@RunAs @RolesAllowed @PermitAll @DenyAll @DeclareRoles) -->
<!-- pre-post-annotations = @PreAuthorized("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')") -->
<global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" 
    jsr250-annotations="disabled"
    pre-post-annotations="disabled">        
</global-method-security>
```

`@Secured` can take a single or several roles.

- `@Secured("ROLE_USER")`
- `@Secured({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"})`  //grand access if the user has one of this roles

BWT: From Spring Security 3 Book (http://www.springsecuritybook.com/):

> The `@Secured` annotation is functionallz and syntactiallz the same as `@RollesAllowed` ... As `@Secured` functions the same as the JSR standard `@RollesAllowed` there's not reallz a compelling reason to use it (`@Secured`) in in new code...

(do not forgett to enable it `jsr250-annotations="enabled"`)

Comment: hi ralph, I have already added the <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" /> in security.xml. But the method checking for security is not working. How do i do?

Comment: @sudo: please descipe your problem appropriate -- in the question text was no explicite question, no hint that anything is not working as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the assertion about `@Secured` annotations being functionally the same as `@RolesAllowed`. If you are just checking for one of a list of roles, then that's probably true, but `@Secured` annotations are more powerful because they use Spring Security's `AccessDecisionManager` and voter system. The attributes aren't limited to simple roles.

Comment: @Luke Taylor: I highly doubt that i a Spring (Secrity) application where  `@RolesAllowed` is used no AccessDecisionManager and voter is used.

Comment: The point is that `RolesAllowed` is only intended to do one thing, based on the JSR-250 spec. It's attributes are consumed by the `Jsr250Voter` and it will allow access if the user has one of those roles. With `@Secured` you can use your own custom voter (or voters) to interpret the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could have multiple roles defined with @Secured annotation . Is this what you need?

If this is the case , try  @RolesAllowed

Answer (score 1):

Check [this FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context). Make sure the `global-method-security` element is in the web context file if you want to apply security to Spring MVC controllers.

Also, you may need to enable class proxying, using

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

if your controller implements an interface and the method you are securing is not part of that interface (you'll also need cglib as an additional dependency in your app for this).

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use annotations, better put the following in servlet.xml. There is no point of enabling the annotations n spring-security-xml as it will not take any effect.

Putting above in servlet.xml will do the trick.